# Separating data in a cell, and copying to another column

Tags: excel, date, vba

I have a column named **Description**, with a description of expenses and an expense date. The file I am getting it from does not have the correct expense date.

I want to separate the data and copy the **date** to the **expense date** column and paste the remaining description to the **Description** column.

The logic in my mind is copy the data and paste to a hidden column and use this code to separate.

```
Sub text2column()

selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("S1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 3), Array(6, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

however I need to paste/overwrite starting on the row that have the resource name (e.g Name1, Name2, Name3, etc..) and leaving the **not available** resource and not touching the description of the **not available** resource.

[image]

Comment: In October, is it `102816homeoffice`? That will foul up a Text-to-Columns based on fixed width.

Comment: Nope, that should be January-28-2016, the data Is 012816home-office

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse. What I'm asking is if the 5 digits preceding Home-Office ever become 6 digits e.g. `122516Home - Office` for 25-Dec-2016. For that matter, in the case of 01-Jan-2016, do they become 4 digits? e.g. `1116Home - Office`.

Comment: Nope. the digits are fixed in 6 digits. the 01-Jan-2016 would be 010116home-office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked how you were basing your processes on the current [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property. I've got some boilerplate framework for working on the selected cells in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020#28700020).

```
Sub splitDescription()
    Dim tmp As String, rng As Range

    With Selection
        For Each rng In .Areas
            With rng
                tmp = Cells(.Cells(1).Row, 16383).Address
                .TextToColumns Destination:=.Parent.Range(tmp), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                               FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 3), Array(6, 1))
                .Offset(0, -2) = .Parent.Range(tmp).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Value
                .Cells = .Parent.Range(tmp).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value
                .Parent.Range(tmp).Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn.Clear
            End With
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

I've added cycling through the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx). This will allow you to cycle through discontiguous ranges of cells in your current selection (e.g. A2:A10, A15:A20). If you have selected a single block of cells, it has an [Areas.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838793.aspx) property of 1 so there is no detriment.

Comment: Thank you for this Jeeped. I will try to work out with your code and will give you a feedback regarding this. Thanks again

Comment: apologies. but I can't give feedback yet. I am still solving how will I tell the program to leave the not available resource. I will also post the code once I solved it. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much Jeeped for that Wonderful code.
I worked it out to solve how will I skip updating the row that has "Not available" value and came up with this code.

```
Sub splitDescription()
    Dim tmp As String, rng As Range

    With selection
        For Each rng In .Areas
            With rng
                tmp = Cells(.Cells(1).Row, 16383).Address
                .TextToColumns Destination:=.Parent.Range(tmp), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                               FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 3), Array(6, 1))
                .Offset(0, -2) = .Parent.Range(tmp).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Value
                .Cells = .Parent.Range(tmp).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value
                .Parent.Range(tmp).Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn.Clear
            End With
        Next rng
    End With

    Range("I4").Select
End Sub

Sub findresource()

    Range("C6").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value = "Not Available"
    selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    selection.Offset(0, 5).Select
    Range(selection, selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Call splitDescription
End Sub
```